# onServiceConnected and onAccessibilityEvent are never being called

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm using accessibility service to detect window changes. I don't know what happened. It was working fine yesterday.

In the settings the service says it's on but neither `onServiceConnected` nor `onAccessibilityEvent` are ever called.

Accessibility service in manifest file:

```
    <service
        android:name=".WindowChangeDetectingService"
        android:label="@string/accessibility_service_name"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.accessibilityservice"
            android:resource="@xml/accessibilityservice" />
    </service>
```

**accessibilityservice**.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<accessibility-service
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:accessibilityEventTypes="typeWindowStateChanged"
    android:accessibilityFeedbackType="feedbackGeneric"
    android:accessibilityFlags="flagIncludeNotImportantViews"
    android:description="@string/accessibility_service_description"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute"/>
```

Accessibility service code:

```
public class WindowChangeDetectingService extends AccessibilityService {

 @Override
    protected void onServiceConnected() {
       ...
    }

 @Override
    public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {
       ...
    }
}
```

I've tried on both real devices and emulators. I've tried whatever I could find on the internet, including restarting the devices. I also restarted the computer. I tried **Rebuild Project** and **Clean Project**. I tried to delete all the code I added today to make it the same as it was yesterday when it was working. I don't know what else to do. Without the accessibility service my app can't exist. Please somebody help! I'll try any suggestion, even if you doubt it will work.

Comment: Try clean rebuild. On a real app uninstall the app and reinstall it. Also check you have the permissions enabled in the emulator / mobile phone. Need to go into app settings and enable the permissions you need. Like location sometimes on restart of the app these are turned off by default. If not you could use an old code version if you have one aka github or zip files you have.

Comment: I tried :( I also don't have the old code anymore :(((((

Comment: You tried running it via a debugger and stepping through?

Comment: My laptop is extremely slow. It needs 30 minutes just to open the emulator. Running the debugger is not possible unfortunately :(

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? onServiceConnected and onAccessibilityEvent never runs for me either.